# Demoiselle JUnit - NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, demoiselle

Ao executar um teste de unidade com
`br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.junit.DemoiselleRunner`, está acontecendo o seguinte erro no final da execução do teste:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.bootstrap.SeBootstrap.removeContexts(SeBootstrap.java:70)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.bootstrap.SeBootstrap$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.removeContexts(SeBootstrap$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:233)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:213)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:117)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:85)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:580)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.junit.DemoiselleRunner.shutdown(DemoiselleRunner.java:88)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.junit.DemoiselleRunner.runChild(DemoiselleRunner.java:63)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.junit.DemoiselleRunner.runChild(DemoiselleRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.junit.DemoiselleRunner.run(DemoiselleRunner.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Trata-se de um módulo da aplicação que roda como um serviço. 
Ou seja, não roda em nenhum servidor de aplicação.
O objetivo de rodar os testes com o `DemoiselleRunner` é para habilitar o CDI.

As dependências do demoiselle que tenho são as seguintes:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

O teste basicamente faz acesso ao banco de dados para ler os dados de uma tabela, e fazer inserção em outra. 
Esqueci de dizer mas estou utilizando JPA e Hibernate na aplicação na parte de acesso a dados. 
E no caso dos testes estou utilizando também DbUnit e o banco HSQLDB em memória.
Durante os testes faço uso do CDI para injetar (@Inject) o EntityManager e um DAO.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você pode dar mais informações sobre o que o seu teste de unidade tenta fazer?

Comment: Ele basicamente faz acesso ao banco de dados para ler os dados de uma tabela, e fazer inserção em outra. 

Esqueci de dizer mas estou utilizando JPA e Hibernate na aplicação. 

E no caso dos testes DbUnit e HSQLDB em memória.

Answer (score 2):

Essa pergunta é bem antiga, mas estou passando por esse problema nesse momento e achei melhor registrar uma resposta.

Investigando percebi que o problema é uma mudança na ordem dos eventos marcados pela interface AfterShutdownProccess quando o Oracle JDK 8 é utilizado.

Mais especificamente, no Oracle JDK8 o método: CustomContextBootstrap#terminateContexts é executado antes de SeBootstrap#removeContexts. Já com o Oracle JDK7 ocorre o contrário.

**Aparentemente** para a execução do DemoiseilleRunner, não é necessário que SeBootstrap#removeContexts seja executado já que CustomContextBootstrap#terminateContexts limpa os contextos. Acredito que não seja possível remover o listener do evento de SeBootstrap#removeContexts programaticamente ou declarativamente sem alterar o código do Demoiseille em si.

Sendo assim o workaround que estou utilizando é utilizar um fork da classe DemoiselleRunner e não disparar o evento, mas executar diretamente CustomContextBootstrap#terminateContexts após a execução do último método de teste:

```
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier;
import org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;

import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.bootstrap.CustomContextBootstrap;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.lifecycle.AfterShutdownProccess;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.lifecycle.AfterStartupProccess;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.util.Beans;

public class CustomDemoiselleRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    private Integer testsLeft;

    public CustomDemoiselleRunner(Class testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
        this.testsLeft = this.testCount();
    }

    @Override
    protected void runChild(FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) {
        super.runChild(method, notifier);

        if (--this.testsLeft == 0) {
            this.shutdown();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        Weld weld = new Weld();
        weld.initialize();

        this.startup();
        super.run(notifier);

        weld.shutdown();
    }

    protected Object createTest() throws Exception {
        return Beans.getReference(getTestClass().getJavaClass());
    }

    private void startup() {
        Beans.getBeanManager().fireEvent(new AfterStartupProccess() {
        });
    }

    private void shutdown() {
        Beans.getReference(CustomContextBootstrap.class).terminateContexts(new AfterShutdownProccess() {
        });;
    }


}
```

Obviamente existe o problema de não disparar algum evento possivelmente necessário para o correto shutdown do Demoiselle, mas parece funcionar até que exista alguma solução definitiva.

Answer (score 0):

Você usou algun arquétipo do Demoiselle para criar a aplicação? Qual é IDE que está usando é Eclipse e qual versão? Teria como enviar o código da classe de testes completo?

- Conforme meu comentário, o erro está vinculado à versão 8 do JDK (1.8.x). Quando este método br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.bootstrap.SeBootstrap.removeContexts executa um desativate dos contextos, eles estão nulos. A implementação para versão 2.4.x foi modificada, por isso os que utilizam a versão 2.3.x do Demoiselle não enfrentam esse problema. A solução, por enquanto, é usar a versão 7 (1.7.x) da JDK. Ou aguardar a solução para o "bug".

Comment: Não foi utilizado nenhum arquétipo do Demoiselle para criar a aplicação. Estou usando o eclipse versão mars. Teria que montar um exemplo de código, gerando o mesmo erro, pois o que tenho não posso disponibilizar. Como não tive tempo de gerar este exemplo, respondi às outras perguntas e em breve disponibilizo um código de exemplo. Obrigado.

Comment: Ok. Mas tenho mais umas perguntas: , qual é o SO que está usando, (linux, windows)? E a versão da JDK (7 ou 8)? Recentemente percebi um problema parecido com este na versão 8 do JDK no windows, mas ainda faltam alguns testes para confirmar se é mesmo a versão da JDK e se também/ou está relacionado com o SO.

Comment: Estou usando Windows 8 e JDK 8. Obrigado.